# How to insert all data from one schema to another schema by MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to copy all data from one schema (a) to another (b).
Two schemas have the same structure.

I use

```
Insert into a.table1 select * from b.table1;
```

But there are 254 tables in a and listing them is very frustrated.

Do you have any better solution?

Thanks

Comment: A quick workaround is to create your insert statements with a select statement: SELECT 'INSERT INTO a.' || table_name || ' SELECT * FROM b.' || table_name || ';' FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'a';

Comment: Well you could always try the utility provided for the purpose [mysqldbcopy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/utils-task-clone-db.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options...

1) Use dynamic SQL to loop through the results of:

`select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables`

2) Output the results of that query into excel, build your inserts from that then run them in a big old proc.

Comment: You can use CONCAT to build the statements directly with SQL, no Excel needed.

Comment: @R.Chappell One more step from there and you've got a dynamic SQL proc... No point going halfway, but I see your point